# PostgreSQL: Inserting into one table then updating another using the same subquery, within the same single query

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, subquery, insert-update

I have a fairly intricate query and I am finding it difficult to create the result of updating two different tables from the same subquery in the `FROM`. The difficulty I am facing is suggesting I have attempted the incorrect flow:

Below is an extremely simplified version of the script I have working for updating table1 from the subquery:

```
UPDATE 
  table1  
SET 
  columnX= subquery.column2
FROM 
  (
  SELECT column1, column2, column2
  FROM table2
) AS subquery
WHERE subquery.column1 = table1.column1;
```

Now I need to bring a third table (table3) into the mix and map table2(subquery).column2 to a value on `INSERT`.
I cannot do this using a second query which would be ideal as the subquery generates UUID's that must persist across the table1.columnX and table3.column1.

Can I include the `INSERT` within the subquery whilst still returning the same subquery table?

Comment: Any advice on forming a better question would be really appreciated.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes sorry, I am all bent over the answer I am not straight on the question. I will update asap"

Comment: are you using uuid_ossp ?

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT`...`RETURNING uuid_column_name` may be the magic you need in your subquery.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-insert.html